# Scala: subtract index of odd values

Tags: scala, patch

For a practical exercise I need to define a function that basically changes the index of every value in an odd index in a list, so that I would get this:

```
changePairs(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)) 
//> res62: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9, 11)

changePairs(List(2,2,30,4,50,6,7,80,9,100)) 
//> res63: List[Int] = List(2, 2, 4, 30, 6, 50, 80, 7, 100, 9)
```

So basically I need to swap the places of each odd-even pair, and in case I'm left with a single odd element at the last index (11 in the first example), I leave it as it is.

I have this but it's definitely not working, and I'm not really sure why.

```
def changePairs(a: List[Int]) = a.zipWithIndex.map {
 case (s,i) => if (i % 2 != 0) a.patch(i,Seq(s),1); a.patch(i-2,Seq(s),0);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If you want to change indices for odd values ony, why are `4` and `6` moved in your second example?

Comment: I don't understand your logic. Your second example has only two odd values (7 and 9), yet a lot more than those two values are changed.

Comment: `a.grouped(2).map(_.reverse).flatten.toList` This question has been asked just a few days ago, but can't find the dupe.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet just noticed that I wrote it wrong, it's not every odd value, but every value in an odd index.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The same as I said to CyrilleCorpet, I had it explained bad, it's not the odd values, but the values at odd indexes.

Comment: @Psidom only saw your comment now, thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
def changePairs(a: List[Int]) = a.grouped(2).flatMap {
  case List(a, b) => List(b, a)
  case a => a
}.toList

changePairs(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) // List(2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7)
```

Main idea that gets you going is once you think of grouping the list into sublists of two elements, which is what `grouped(2)` does. From then on it's an easy ride - describe two cases, one with two elements (in that case we flip them) and one with only one element, such as 7 in my example, in which case we just leave it be. We use `flatMap` to flatten the resulting list of 2-element lists into one big list, and we do `.toList` to get out of an iterator that we got from `grouped`.

EDIT:

I now saw `a.grouped(2).map(_.reverse).flatten.toList` in the comments. Yeah, that works too, it's the same as this but much less verbose since instead of "manually" swapping the elements, we just do a `reverse` on each sublist.

Comment: Use the best of both answers: `a.grouped(2).flatMap(_.reverse).toList`. When you're playing [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) every stroke counts.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use recursion and pattern matching. This is efficient as you are only going through the list once:

```
def changePairs(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  l match {
    case a :: b :: tail => b :: a :: changePairs(tail)
    case _ => Nil
  }
}
```